# MySQL Stored Procedure Temporary Table - ORDER BY varchar Field Not Sorting

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I've tried digging for an answer for this but have been unsuccessful.

I have a MySQL 5.6 stored proc that creates a temp table.  Inside that temp table is a varchar(50) field.

I insert data into that temp table within my stored proc, and then I return it via a simple select with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_table ORDER BY a ASC, b ASC;
```

...where "b" is the varchar field.  "a" is a datetime field.

The datetime sort is just fine, but even if I remove the initial sort, I still don't get the proper sorting by column b.

I've tried setting the collation type, character sets, etc. on both the field and the table.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**

SHOW CREATE TABLE ... returns:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_table` (  
  `d_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
  `d_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `d_type_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,  
  `d_value` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SHOW FULL COLUMNS FOR ... returns:

```
+------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field            | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| d_date           | datetime     | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| d_type_id        | int(11)      | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| d_type_name      | varchar(50)  | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| d_value          | decimal(6,3) | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+------------------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

When I call the stored proc, I sort first by "d_date" (this is the "a" column from the query above), and then "d_type_name" (the "b" column from above).  I actually do a third sort by "d_value" but even if I ONLY sort by "d_type_name", I still don't get the expected sorting results.

Here's what I'm expecting:

```
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| d_date              | d_type_id      | d_type_name      | d_value   |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     4.800 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.200 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     4.200 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.500 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     1.250 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     2.000 |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| d_date              | d_type_id      | d_type_name      | d_value   |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-28 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     4.800 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-02-29 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     4.200 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.200 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-01 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              4 | P                |     2.000 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              3 | E                |     1.250 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              1 | B                |     0.500 |
| 2016-03-02 00:00:00 |              2 | O                |     0.000 |
+---------------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+
```

Is that sufficient?  I'm really hoping I'm missing something really obvious (been under the weather for a couple days so you never know).  Thanks again.

Comment: Add the output from a `show create table tmp_table;`

Comment: Also run `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tmp_table;` and add to your post what the character set and collation is for column `b`.

Comment: Can you show some sample data, the result you expect, and the result you're getting instead?

Comment: Finally, provide an example of a few b entries in the order they were sorted from

Comment: Is the stored procedure really relevant? What happens if you try the same thing outside a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, the stored proc is relevant.  If I do the same sort with a normal (i.e. not marked 'temporary') table, everything works just fine.  I'll update my question with the requests above.  I'll modify the stored proc to not drop the temp table after and run those commands.